# Cheaper Rehearsals - Regular Practicing

Tags: practice, band, rehearsal

Most bands / solo artists seem to be skint so where are they practising / rehearsing? (Especially if you need to be practising twice a week or more, and can't practice at home)

Studio prices don't appear to be cheap, and renting a rehearsal space seems neat but you sometimes have to share the room and trust your gear to a stranger/landlord (And not viable if you're not a 3 piece band or more)

Answer (score 5):

Most bands especially when they are starting out use one of their band mate's houses to practice. It will typically be at the drummers house since that is typically the hardest instrument to move. A little more specifically if they practice at a band mate's house rehearsal will typically be in the garage or basement as that is again typically where someone will put drums.

Ever heard of the term "garage band"?

Comment: beat me for 5 seconds!

Comment: @Shevliaskovic sorry about that.

Comment: Last time I used a garage, the neighbour threatened to call the police when I turned my mates marshal stack up to 3 (out of ten)

Comment: @Dom I thought Shevliaskovic meant he wanted spanking for a small amount of time lol

Answer (score 3):

Rehearsal studios are indeed a luxury. Different people have different circumstances, but the kind of solutions include:

- Homes / sheds / garages
- Back rooms/cellars/attics of shops/pubs/etc.
- School/church/community halls
- Offices after hours
- The street
- Barns/warehouses

... through a variety of legitimate and illegitimate means -- I'm sure there will be bands out there who trespassed in some derelict building for all their early rehearsing.

Consider that a full band including a drumkit can fit into a small caravan, if they're willing to squeeze up.

If you're an amplified band, consider that you don't have to rehearse at full volume every time - especially if the drummer has some electronic drums (if he doesn't, then rehearse wherever he practices drums!)

Consider that amps and other electronics can run off batteries; you don't have to rehearse somewhere with power.

If you really want a studio, you could ask if they have lower rates late at night or early in the morning.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard of some storage locker units that will accept bands renting large units for practice space. Not all are band friendly however.

Answer (score 2):

Practice hubs are available for a price. Provided the drummer has an electronic kit, they can work well. Everybody plugs in, vox uses a mic, and each player can have his own mix,in a pair of headphones, and deafen himself if he feels the need.I'm guessing that mains voltage is not necessary, so Slim's caravan idea, with a 12v battery would be good.

Practice (rehearsal or jam) hubs are like mixers and p.a. amps all in one box. Each player plugs the instrument in, and listens to the resultant mix (his own personal mix) through headphones.Around £4oo buys one that will service up to 7 musos. That's about 30 odd hrs worth of studio time, and no-one needs to be deafened by the guy who plays loudest!

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what practice hubs are. I am sure I could look it up, but perhaps it would improve your answer. In fact it looks really cool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what skint means, but my band rents studio space once a week at $40 (USD) for two hours. Split amongst the three of us.

Comment: I worked (for a short time) with a band that had its own studio. When it was pointed out that we may earn £1500 in a year, they looked pleased. Then it was pointed out that would just pay for the room. Earning less = skint!

Comment: That's still $2000 a year, just for 2 hours a week

Comment: fyi Skint = having little/no money

Answer (score 1):

You can often hire church halls or that kind of thing very cheaply. It probably depends on your music and looks though - a scary punk band might struggle more than a Christian worship group!

But schools, churches, etc are worth approaching.

Comment: Absolutely - practice studios around my way (south east England) are about £30-£50 for 4 hours with a PA provided. Hiring a room in a local school = £20 or so for 4 hours. Some are cheaper. You have to take your own gear (PA/amp/drums) of course, but if you're 'financially challenged', this is a great answer. The scool I have used literally rents out a classroom so you have to move the chairs about etc first and put it back afterwards.